# Getting map by id or class using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers

How can I get hold of a OpenLayers3 `map` object associated with a specific id or class (unique)?

I searched and found [this thread](https://www.drupal.org/node/1243370), which says something like:

```
var map = $('.my_map_class').data('openlayers'); //assuming there is just one map on the page
```

But I got an typeerror saying that map is not defined. I have tried replacing `$` with `jQuery`, and it didn't work either.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 6):

Your code snippet would work if a reference to the map object was added to the DOM element using jQuery's `data` function. With something like this:

```js
$('.my_map_class').data('openlayers', mapObject);
```

But OpenLayers does not do that for you. (OpenLayers is not even based on jQuery.)

So if you want to get a reference to the map object from the DOM element using jQuery you have to add that reference yourself, using `data` as done above.

This is what I'd do:

```js
var map = new ol.Map({
  target: 'map'
  // ...
});
$('#map').data('map', map);
```

With that you can get a reference to the map using:

```js
var map = $('#map').data('map');
```

Comment: For use without jQuery: `document.getElementById("map").data = map;` and `var map = document.getElementById("map").data;`